# How to install GNU Make 4.0 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, make

I need GNU Make 4.0+ because of the new `file` function.

How can I install this on Ubuntu 12.04?

I tried the .deb, but it depends on libc6 2.17.

Answer (score 2):

For folks like you I have just put a [64-bit amd deb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bashdb/files/remake/4.1%2Bdbg-1.0/remake_4.1%2Bdbg1.0_amd64.deb/download) of [remake](http://bashdb.sf.net/remake) for Ubuntu 12.04. *remake* is GNU Make with some extensions. The specific version I used was 4.1.

Comment: Thank you for remake, I'm going to try it out. Just letting you know that your package can not be installed at the same time as Ubuntu's make-4 package.  dpkg: error processing archive /home/thomas/Downloads/remake_4.1+dbg1.0_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/gnumake.h', which is also in package make 4.0-8

Comment: Does adding --replacefiles take care of this?  I'm quite sure what the best way to handle this on the packing side is yet.

Comment: @rocky, any updates on this install. I just tried to install the file you linked to and I get the same error, that it is trying to overwrite gnumake.h. It doesn't seem like --replacefiles is even a valid option.